# How can you use group by in SQL and aggregate counts per values in a column (category or item type)?

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table that looks like this:

| customer_num | item |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | dress |
| 2000 | dress |
| 1000 | pants |
| 3000 | undies |
| 1000 | undies |
| 2000 | dress |

And I want a table that counts the number of transactions that each customer_num has made per item type:

| customer_num | dress | pants | undies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2000 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3000 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

So far, I have used the group by function to count the number of transactions per customer. But this only gives me the transactions per customer_num and not segregated by item type:

```
SELECT customer_num, count(*) from table GROUP BY customer_num
```

I tried further by using multiple column names in group by but it just outputs the count per customer_num and item pair. How can I generate an output similar to the sample above, where the columns are the item, and the rows are the unique customer_num?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select customer_num,
       sum(case when item_type = 'dress' then 1 else 0 end) as dress,
       sum(case when item_type = 'pants' then 1 else 0 end) as pants,
       sum(case when item_type = 'undies' then 1 else 0 end) as undies
from t
group by customer_num;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Tried this and it worked. Question, what if you don't know the exact item types or if the list is dynamic? I know you can select distinct the column to know all the values but is there a way to do this without writing a sum line query for each item?

Comment: @JMDR . . . A query returns a fixed list of columns.  If you want them to be dynamic, you will need to construct the query as a string and then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Use subqueries and join on customer_num

```
SELECT  
    customer_num,dress, pant, ...
FROM
    (SELECT 
         customer_num, COUNT(*) AS dress 
     FROM 
         table 
     WHERE 
         item_type = 'dress' 
     GROUP BY 
         customer_num) r1
JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         customer_num, COUNT(*) AS pant 
     FROM 
         table  
     WHERE 
         item_type = 'pan'  
     GROUP BY 
         customer_num) r2 USING (customer_num)
JOIN ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply **PIVOT** the table as below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT customer_num,item from table
)
PIVOT
(
COUNT(item)
FOR item in ('dress','pants','undies')
)
ORDER BY customer_num;
```